# How to find the maximum value for each key in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say for example I have the dictionary

```
{'Yellow': [1,5,7]},'Red': [10,5,2],'Blue': [8,4,2]
```

How would I print the dictionary by highest value for each key, I would want it to print:

```
Red: 10
Blue: 8
Yellow: 7
```

Comment: `print("\n".join("{}: {}".format(key, max(value)) for key, value  in mydict))`

Comment: @zondo You are missing `.items()`... `print("\n".join("{}: {}".format(key, max(value)) for key, value in mydict.items()))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
items = sorted(((k, max(v)) for (k, v) in d.items()), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
for k, m in items: 
    print (k, ':', m)
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each `(k, v)` pair in the dictionary, and print the key `k` followed by the `max()` of the value `v`:

```
d = {'Yellow': [1,5,7],'Red': [10,5,2],'Blue': [8,4,2]}

for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: max(v[1]), reverse=True):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, max(v)))
```

**Output**

```
Red: 10
Blue: 8
Yellow: 7
```

Comment: I think the OP also wants the dict sorted in descending order.

Comment: You are right - I stupidly only focused on the title. I will update.

Comment: Well... I wouldn't say the OP is blameless. The wording could have been a lot better.